# Nested quotes CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a CSV file with some entries that have a strange structure, using nested quotes mixed with new lines, like this:

```
"user","date","msg"
"User1","1234","Hello. She said "well, thats good"
then
fade out"
```

I already tested many csv reader setups (the python3 native csv reader) but i'm not capable of reading this file properly. The output should be:

> ['User1', '1234', 'Hello. She said "well, thats good" then fade out']

but using, for example,    `csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', doublequote=True, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)`
it outputs:

> ['User1', '1234', 'Hello. She said well', ' thats good"']

showing that it is unable to parse the nested quotes neither the text in the other lines.

How can I properly parse this file?

Comment: you can't. Either you need doubled up inner quotes `"""Hi"" she said."`or escaped inner quotes `"\"Hi\" she said."` - you would need to preprocess and fix your file.

Comment: You can't expect your CSV reader to know which line is valid and which isn't. If you have bad input, parse it yourself. You might want to look into regex (`re`) to parse it, it isn't that difficult.

Comment: Yes, I've tried your solution of double up quotes. I was able to double up quotes between a unique word (using regex), but I couldn't double up quotes between a sentence, because sometimes it screw up the quotes between the csv fields. Could you help me with this regex rule? I'm using `re`.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to fix the file - and without more information I'm not sure anyone can tell you the best way to do it. Here's the problem. If you read in your example csv exactly as it is, this is what you end up with:

`"user","date","msg"\n"User1","1234","Hello. She said "well, thats good"\nthen\nfade out"`

There is no good way to tell which quotes are which, which commas are which and which new lines (`\n`) are 'good' and which are 'bad'. In a properly formatted csv, a `\n` character means it's a new row (i.e. a new entry) so if a csv has one entry split across multiple lines the csv needs to be fixed first.